# Php login system suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I built a PHP/MySql login system for a website I am working on and all was working fine. I took a month off from working on it, pulled it up last night, and all of a sudden it doesn't work. It recognizes if a wrong username or password was entered, but if you enter the correct information it redirects you to the login page again. Was there some update somewhere that I am unaware of? I did not change anything in any of my files. It was working perfectly a month ago, and with no change at all it doesn't work now. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It is working if I check the remember me box, but not if I don't I will paste my code below:

Login Script:

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

session_name('TheLoginSession');

session_start();

// ---------- LOGIN ---------- 

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{   
// Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

$err = array();
// Will hold our errors


if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
    $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

if(!count($err))
{
    $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['remembercheck'] = (int)$_POST['remembercheck'];

    $storedsaltquery = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT rand FROM members WHERE usr =   '".$_POST['username']."'"));
    $storedsalt = $storedsaltquery['rand'];

    // Escaping all input data

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,compid,usr,firstName,level,yn FROM members WHERE usr='{$_POST['usernamelog']}' AND pass='".hash("sha256",$_POST['passwordlog'].$storedsalt)."'"));

    if($row['id'])
    {
        // If everything is OK login

        $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['comp']=$row['compid'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['firstName'];
        $_SESSION['usrlevel'] = $row['level'];
        $_SESSION['new'] = $row['yn'];
        $_SESSION['remembercheck'] = $_POST['remembercheck'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('Remember','remembercheck',time()+1209600,'/','.domain.com');

    }
    else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
}

if($err)
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
// Save the error messages in the session

echo header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
}
```

Index Page:

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'includes/connect.php';
require 'includes/functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined

session_name('TheLoginSession');
// Starting the session

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['Remember']) && !$_SESSION['remembercheck'])

{
// If you are logged in, but you don't have the Remember cookie (browser restart)
// and you have not checked the remembercheck checkbox:

$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

// Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}
if($_SESSION['id'] && $_SESSION['new'] != 1){
header("Location: home.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Did your database get dropped or reset? **Do you have backups** you can compare against?

Comment: Has there been an update to your server? do you have control over the server? Are there any errors displayed or logged? What have you tried to do to debug the problem? With so little information no one can help you. The problem will be to do with your code or server configuration.

Comment: had similar problem a few weeks ago when host did a php upgrade and sessions weren't being stored properly, they were always empty array until host fixed mapping or whatever

Comment: Given your cookie lifetime is about 2 weeks, it is very plausible that it is an old cookie interfering, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

How can there be an update if nothing's changed?

Are you using a CMS or framework?

If it's all your own code, and you haven't changed anything, then nothing would have updated.

Comment: I don't know, maybe a JS update or something? I am baffled and I don't know what to do to fix it since it was working fine when I worked on it last.

Comment: Are you able to turn on PHP errors or some kind of error reporting?

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue like this before but without more information, hard to know if it is the same issue. Mine had the symptom you describe (login with bad creds and get the authentication error, login with good creds and redirect back to login).

Mine was due to failing to include code to remove old session cookies. The login attempt 'works' but an old cookie also read and attempts to authenticate, fails (because it is too old), and kicks the user back to login.

If this is your issue, clear your site cookies and see if you can then log in.

If that works, you'll want to add some cleanup code to your logout and stale session handling. For instance, for logging out:

```
  // per http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
  $params["path"], $params["domain"],
  $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  session_destroy();
```

Again, just guessing at your issue here.

Comment: adjust the parts of setcookie to match the one you want destroyed, of course, just an example here.